# Subscribing to an event in COM object is ignored

Tags: c#, events, vbscript, com, event-handling

In a class I have a constructor that receives a `SerialPort` object that it needs to initialize. As part of the initialization a subscriber method is added to the `DataReceived` event. This works as expected when it executes as a standard Windows Forms App.

But I’m also going to use this class as a COM object that can be called from a VBScript.

My problem is, that when I run the code as a Windows Forms App it works well. But when it’s used as a COM object the subscriber method is “ignored”.

To test this I’ve added some `messagebox.show()` calls and the results I get are as follows.

When run as Windows Forms App I’ll see the **“Set subscriber method”** message and when data is received on the serial port I’ll see the **“Found data”** message.
When called as a COM object I’ll see the **“Set subscriber method”** message but NOT the **“Found data”** message.

I’ve run out of ideas and I can’t find anything online that should suggest that subscribing to an event in a COM object should be anything different than subscribing to an event in a Windows Forms App.

Am I missing something here?

```
//Constructor
public RFIDBoard(SerialPort mSerialPort)
{
    UUIDonBoard = new byte[SetUpValues.NUM_BYTES_IN_RFID_UUID];
    HoldsAProductRFID = false;
    sp = mSerialPort;
    sp.BaudRate = 9600;
    sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    sp.Parity = Parity.None;
    sp.DataBits = 8;
    sp.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 4;
    MessageBox.Show("Set subscriber method");
    sp.DataReceived += Sp_DataReceived;
}

//Subscriber method when data is received
private void Sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found data");
    GetDataFromPort();
    if (OnBoardStatusChange != null)
        OnBoardStatusChange(this, e);

}
```

**EDIT**
Added the VBSCript used to create the COM object.

```vbs
Dim oArduino

'Create COM object
Set oArduino = WScript.CreateObject("ArduinoRFID")

'Show main form that pick up serial data
oArduino.ShowMe()

Loopit = True

'Start loop and look for new data
Do While Loopit

    'If boolean IsDataReady in COM object is true then new data has arrived   
    If oArduino.IsDataReady = True Then

        theBoard1 = oArduino.Prod1
        theBoard2 = oArduino.Prod2
        theBoard3 = oArduino.Prod3

        'Reset IsDataReady
        oArduino.IsDataReady = False

    end If
    'Limit the stress on COM by only asking twice a minute for new data
    WScript.Sleep(500)
Loop
```

Comment: What is your VBScript code. How are you running VBScript. VBScript in Windows Script Host needs special event treatment. You must use `wsh.createobject` not vbscript's `createobject`. Also you need to loop and `wsh.sleep` to wait for events else your vbscript exits before events arrive.

Comment: Two nasty bugs in this code.  Using MessageBox in an event that is raised on a worker thread is very troublesome.  The box can't find an owner, it can easily disappear behind the window of another app.  Quite likely when using the VBScript interpreter.  Minimize windows one by one to find it back.  And worse, the code does not set the Handshake property.  That makes it work only by accident, depending on how it was left by another program that was run before.  If you have no idea what to select then pick None and set the RtsEnable and DtrEnable properties to true.

Comment: @ACatInLove I've added the VBScript. I changed it to use WSH - but the problem remains. I'll do some more testing with other COM objects and using your suggestion when creating the object in VBS. I'll be back with results.

Comment: @MickyD From the other posts i've seen, then VBS should be able to use COM objects that internally uses events. The event problem is IN the C# program - not in VBS. The core of the problem is that that eventhandler in the serialport object is "ignored". I can't say if the event is wired but never called or if the wiring is never done. The problem only exists when using the COM object in VBS where as it works if the code is executed as a stand-alone windows forms app.

Comment: @HansPassant The message box is ONLY there for testing purpose. And what I can see is that the message box in the `Sp_DataReceived` method is never shown when used as a COM object where as it WILL show when executing as a windows forms app. I'm sure the message box never shows. I've minimized and used CTRL+TAB - it's not showing. I'm quite sure the event is never fired. I'll insert the handshake property as suggested and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Well, luckily I saw two bugs.  Asking "how to debug my C# code when run by a vbscript program" is probably not going to hurt you.  Well, easy to explain in a comment, use Project > Properties > Debug tab, "Start external program" radio button.

Comment: @HansPassant That's very nice to know. Thanks !! As you can tell - I'm new to all of this so I'm learning every day :-D But - can you tell me more about how this can help my debug process? I can check the "Start External Program" button - but the VBScript is in a .VBS file. It's not an .EXE file.

Comment: Use c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe, argument is your .vbs file.  Could also be wscript.exe or stored in syswow64, you didn't tell me enough about it.

Comment: OMG - why didn't I think of that ?? Sure - I can simply run the cscript.exe.Thanks !! I'm still testing and will post my findings if I can be more specific with the new "tool" at hand...